# Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: '

Tags: laravel

I am writing an app in laravel which displays this error SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'medicals' (SQL: select * from `patients` left join `medicals` on `medicals`.`patients_id` = `patients`.`id` left join `medicals` on `medicals`.`trx_id` = `patient_referral`.`trx_id`)

```
  return Patients::where(function ($q) use ($startdate, $enddate, $id) {
        $q->where("patient_referral.trx_id",  $id);
    })
        ->leftJoin("medicals", "medicals.patients_id", "=", "patients.id")
        ->leftJoin("medicals", "medicals.trx_id", "=", "patient_referral.trx_id")
        ->get();
```

Medical Model

```
class Medicals extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];

public function patients()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Patients::class, "id", "patients_id");
}
public function tests()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Tests::class);
}
}
```

Patient Model

class Patients extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];

```
public function medicals()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Medicals::class);
}

public function patient_referral()
{
    return $this->hasMany(PatientReferral::class);
}
```

}

Patient Referral Model

class PatientReferral extends Model
{
protected $guarded = [];

```
protected $table = "patient_referral";


public function patients()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Patients::class);
}
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are trying to join `medicals` table twice so in this case you need to provide unique alias to each instance and in join clause specify that alias for columns so that database will know the exact column from table to use in filter like

```
Patients::where(function ($q) use ($startdate, $enddate, $id) {
            $q->where("patient_referral.trx_id",  $id);
        })
        ->leftJoin("medicals as a", "a.patients_id", "=", "patients.id")
        ->leftJoin("medicals as b", "b.trx_id", "=", "patient_referral.trx_id")
        ->get();
```

Comment: @Khalid I am getting unknown column patient_referral.trx_id and I have the column in the database

Comment: @mychuks are you sure `trx_id` belongs `patient_referral` table if so then you need to join this table in query